# Proxy configuration in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to configure the proxy in my Scrapy project. It throws the following error when I try to run it:

**Error**

```
2019-05-09 19:36:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-05-09 19:36:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.myip.com/> (failed 1 times): Could not open CONNECT tunnel with proxy x.x.x.x:xxxx [{'status': 407, 'reason': b'Unauthorized'}]
```

**Code**

```
class FirstSpyder(CrawlSpider):
    # The name of the spider
    name = "FirstSpyder"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstSpyder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.proxy_pool = ['http://x.x.x.x:xxxx']

    # The domains that are allowed (links to other domains are skipped)
    allowed_domains = ["myip.com"]

    # The URLs to start with
    start_urls = ['https://www.myip.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            request = Request(url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse)
            # set the meta['item'] to use the item in the next call back
            request.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(self.proxy_pool)
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        ip = response.css('#ip::text').get()
        print ("IPV4::",ip)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well from the error it's returning, as you can see its says 'Unauthorized'.

Status code 407 stands for: "*The HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication Required client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for a proxy server that is between the browser and the server that can access the requested resource.*"

Without seeing a bit of your code, can't help you out much...

And there is a library that will help you to do this:
https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies